# Unrar specific files using wildcards

Tags: files, wildcards, rar

I want to extract only a specific file type using unrar.

With unzip command I can extract all archives with a specific extension.

```
unzip "$FileName" *[.txt,.TXT]
```

How can I do the same with unrar? Do I need to iterate through every file?

Comment: `unrar "$FileName" '*.txt'`

Comment: @SatoKatsura Does it work for both types? Some people capitalize extensions. I guess for now I'll lower-case the extension variable.

Comment: There are switches to change names to lower or upper case.  Maybe they are applied before matching.

Comment: I guess it's better to lower-case if I want to extract multiple formats. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unrar x "$FileName" \*.txt \*.TXT
```

In bash you can also use:

```
unrar x "$FileName" \*.{txt,TXT}
```

Bash transforms this to the former form.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I give my thanks cheers